# setting up the timedate string so that it can be manipulated on a different webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

      string timedate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:tt");

      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

      }
```

Comment: Could you explain the problem better please?

Comment: Wait... whats the question?

Comment: First time I have typed this...Could you ask a question with the code you've shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly and you need to share data between 2 pages (webforms) you can use Session:

e.g. on one page:

```
string timedate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:tt");
Session["timedate"] = timedate;
```

on another page:

```
string timedate;

if (Session["timedate"] != null) {
    timedate = Session["timedate"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: getting this error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You have to make sure value is set. E.g. first part of the code must run before u accessing the second part. To prevent the error I added the check.